# MongoDB's "mongosniff" for windows

Tags: mongodb, fiddler

I need to see the request/response to a mongo server. MongoDB has an application called "mongosniff", but it isn't available on windows.

What is my alternative? Fiddler?

Comment: Wireshark would be another option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mongosniff` isn't included with the binary download for Windows, but you can compile it yourself if you are patient and so inclined.  You will need to install developer tools including [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/), [Scons](http://www.scons.org/), and the [WinPcap developer's pack](http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm) so this certainly isn't a quick path.

I would instead recommend downloading [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which is a cross-platform  network protocol analyzer.  In fact, I would recommend using Wireshark in preference to `mongosniff` even if you aren't using Windows.

Wireshark also uses the WinPcap library and provides a much more comprehensive user interface than `mongosniff` as well as a huge selection of [supported protocols](http://wiki.wireshark.org/ProtocolReference) including the [Mongo Wire Protocol](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Mongo).

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is a web proxy for debugging HTTP/HTTPS traffic, and isn't directly relevant to the Mongo Wire Protocol.  You could use Fiddler to inspect a web interface (eg. REST API), but it does not decode lower level protocols.

Comment: Correct; you can use Wireshark or NetMon (fiddler2.com/r/?NetMon) for this task. Fiddler can view traffic for protocols that tunnel over HTTP/HTTPS but not those that run on lower-level TCP/IP.